# Autohotkey: What is the keycode for for the following keys

Tags: c#, c, keyboard, autohotkey

I use autohotkey programming, and I Know that the (C) key code is {VK43}, the (X) key code is {VK58}.
I want to know the code of the following keys:([),(]),(`),('),(,),(.)and(/)
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can find out by yourself

```
foreach (var ch in "CX[]`',./")
{
    Console.WriteLine(ch + " " + ((int)ch).ToString("X2"));
}
```